# Removing part of URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, subdirectory

I have searched a lot but none of the answers I found did the trick. Basically I have a domain (example.com) but my website is in a subvolder(v4)

I have done it so that when people type in www.example.de they get redirected to www.example.de/v4/ which is what I wanted, but my client doesn't want people to see the /v4/ part in the URL.

I have two .htaccess files, the one in the root is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /v4/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v4/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v4/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.de$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /v4/index.php [L]
```

The one in the /v4 subfolder is:

```
RewriteBase /v4/
RewriteRule ^v4/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /v4/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^v4/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R]
```

I would really appreciate any help in making the /v4/ in the URL invisible, thanks in advance

Comment: Is that your entire .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

You can have these .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v4/$1 [L]
```

The one in the /v4 subfolder should be:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v4/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```